# NoClassDefFoundError running Java terminal command using the "-jar"

Tags: java, jar

I have a (Windows 10, Oracle SDK Java-12) Java program in a jar that uses a utility in another jar in a different directory.

I can't run successfully the Java terminal command using the `-jar` format; only the `mainclass` format works for me. The utility classes can't be found if using `-jar`.

I inferred from the Java program help (below) and many other references that `-jar program.jar` with a manifest entry `Main-Class: app.Main` would be equivalent to using the `app.Main` mainclass. It doesn't work if using two different directories so how am I wrong?

Absolute paths to different directories seems to be messing up.  There are about a 1000 similar questions answered but I don't see an answer to this detail. (Note I have also tried several experiments using the manifest Class-Path which seems similar in action to the -cp option.)

c:>`java`

Usage: java [options] mainclass [args...]

```
       (to execute a class)
```

or  java [options] -jar jarfile [args...]

```
       (to execute a jar file)
```

File `c:\AA\program.jar` has a manifest with `Main-Class: app.Main`

File `c:\BB\utility.jar`

> `c:\java -cp c:\AA;c:\BB; -jar c:\AA\program.jar`
>
> Main loads and gets Exception NoClassDefFoundError for the class in
> c:\BB\utility.jar

> `c:\java -cp c:\AA\program.jar;c:\BB\utility.jar; -jar c:\AA\program.jar`
>
> Same as above Main loads and gets Exception NoClassDefFoundError for
> the class in c:\BB\utility.jar

> `c:\java -cp c:\AA\program.jar;c:\BB\utility.jar; -jar program.jar`
>
> Unable to access jarfile program.jar (disappointing that it didn't
> search classpath but I suppose not unreasonable)

> `c:\java -cp c:\AA;c:\BB app.Main`
>
> Cannot find app.Main (need filename or "*" on classpath)

> `c:\java -cp c:\AA\program.jar;c:\BB\utility.jar; app.Main`
>
> Works okay

Comment: You can't combine java -jar with -cp. Either you use java -jar either java -cp.

If you want to use only java -jar you have to create a uber jar and for this you can use maven-shade-plugin

Comment: Thanks. Given this right answer I was able to find the correct java.exe documentation at Oracle. "When you use -jar, the specified JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other class path settings are ignored."